# New line not allowend in \rput in pgfornaments?

Tags: errors, diagrams

[image]
Above code is resulted from the following code -

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
%\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,banglattfont=Siyam Rupali]{latexbangla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzrput}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} 
\begin{document}  
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}   
\unitlength=1cm   

\begin{center}   
\begin{picture}(10,10)%
  \color{Blue}%
   \put(0,0){\framebox(10,10){%
   \rput[tl](-3,5){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{71}}%
   \rput[bl](-3,-5){\pgfornament[width=6cm,,symmetry=h]{71}}%
   \rput[tl](-5,5){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}}%
   \rput[tr](5,5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=v]{63}}%
   \rput[bl](-5,-5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=h]{63}}%
   \rput[br](5,-5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,,symmetry=c]{63}}%
   \rput[bl]{-90}(-5,3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
   \rput[bl]{90}(5,-3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
 \rput(0,0){\Huge \color{Maroon}\textbf{Helal}\\Belal}}%
   \rput[b](0,0.5){\pgfornament[width=5cm]{69}}%
   \rput[t](0,-0.5){\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{69}}%
%   \rput[tr]{-30}(-1,2.5){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{57}}%
%   \rput[tl]{30}(1,2.5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{57}}}}% 
 }}
\end{picture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` to get a line break. There is also the extra brace after that line, as Thruston remarked in a comment, and you have two extra braces after the final (commented) ornament.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
%\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush,banglattfont=Siyam Rupali]{latexbangla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzrput}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} 
\begin{document}  
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}   
\unitlength=1cm   

\begin{center}   
\begin{picture}(10,10)%
  \color{Blue}%
   \put(0,0){\framebox(10,10){%
   \rput[tl](-3,5){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{71}}%
   \rput[bl](-3,-5){\pgfornament[width=6cm,,symmetry=h]{71}}%
   \rput[tl](-5,5){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}}%
   \rput[tr](5,5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{63}}%
   \rput[bl](-5,-5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{63}}%
   \rput[br](5,-5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{63}}%
   \rput[bl]{-90}(-5,3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
   \rput[bl]{90}(5,-3){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}}%
   \rput(0,0){\Huge \color{Maroon}%
              \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
               \textbf{Helal}\\[-7pt]
                Belal
               \end{tabular}}%
   \rput[b](0,1){\pgfornament[width=5cm]{69}}% % moved this up
   \rput[t](0,-1){\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{69}}% % moved this down
   \rput[tr]{-30}(-1,2.5){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{57}}%
   \rput[tl]{30}(1,2.5){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{57}}%  %removed two braces here
 }}
\end{picture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```